# ansible_default_ipv4.address Ip address range

Tags: ansible

The playbook I'm writing can run on multiple environments and each environment is on a different subnet.

I'm writing a conditional block which will only run if the host IP is of the range I will specify in the condition

e.g.

if `ansible_default_ipv4.address` is in one below IPs

- 192.168.4.41 or 192.168.4.42 or 192.168.4.81 or 192.168.4.82
- 192.168.5.41 or 192.168.5.42 or 192.168.5.81 or 192.168.5.82
- 192.168.6.41 or 192.168.6.42 or 192.168.6.81 or 192.168.6.82
- ... and so on

I can add each IP one by one but this seems inefficient, repetitive and will make the playbook lengthy. Is there a way we can add the range in the condition?

Also, if possible, how can I force to run only on GroupA or GroupB or GroupC servers?

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking there are no IP ranges in your example, only discrete IP addresses on different subnets.

In such a scenario, I would list the prefixes and suffixes I want to use and create a list of all of them using the [`product` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) and [mapping](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) the [`join` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings).

```yaml
prefixes:
  - 192.168.4
  - 192.168.5
  - 192.168.6
suffixes:
  - 41
  - 42
  - 82
all_ips: "{{ prefixes | product(suffixes) | map('join', '.') }}"
```

Which gives when expanded

```json
    "all_ips": [
        "192.168.4.41",
        "192.168.4.42",
        "192.168.4.82",
        "192.168.5.41",
        "192.168.5.42",
        "192.168.5.82",
        "192.168.6.41",
        "192.168.6.42",
        "192.168.6.82"
    ]
```

You can then use that expression in a condition:

```yaml
when: ansible_default_ipv4.address in all_ips
```

Now if I understand correctly, you want each set of IPs on a specific subnet to be the marker of a specific group. You can do that dynamically in your playbook. Here is an example to give you the global idea. I only partially tested it so there might be some leftover typos (let me know or even edit the answer if it's obvious). Note that the `prefixes` variable is a bit different from above to accommodate with the needed groups declarations.

```yaml
- name: gather facts from all host and create dynamic groups
  hosts: all
  
  vars:
    prefixes:
      192.168.4: dyn_group_A
      192.168.5: dyn_group_B
      192.168.6: dyn_group_C

    suffixes:
      - 41
      - 42
      - 82

    all_ips: "{{ prefixes.keys() | product(suffixes) | map('join', '.') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: tag needed targets with a fact
      vars:
        host_prefix: "{{ (ansible_default_ipv4.address | split('.'))[:3] | join('.') }}"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        my_dyn_group: "{{ prefixes[host_prefix] }}"
      when: ansible_default_ipv4.address in all_ips

    - name: create overall and specific dynamic groups from tagged targets
      ansible.builtin.add_host:
        name: "{{ item.inventory_hostname }}"
        groups:
          - dyn_group_overall
          - "{{ item.my_dyn_group }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) | selectattr('my_dyn_group', 'defined') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.inventory_hostname }}"

    - name: a single task that would play on all valid hosts and skip on others
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "I would run on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['dyn_group_overall']

    - name: a single task that would run only on group B hosts and skip on others
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "I would run on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['dyn_group_B']

# Note that limiting a task by condition to a group
# in a wider targeted play as above is usually not a good practice.
# It is much more efficient on most occasion to target
# the needed group in a specific play

- name: tasks to be played on all matched hosts
  hosts: dyn_group_overall
  # Facts are already gathered above so skip it
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: This will only play on targeted host

- name: tasks to be played on hosts in group C
  hosts: dyn_group_C
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: This will only play on hosts in group C
```